# composite foreign key add fails

Tags: mysql, database

I have got 4 tables here:

```
CREATE TABLE paper (
id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30)
) ENGINE =INNODB;

CREATE TABLE subscriber (
id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
address VARCHAR(30),
suburb VARCHAR(20),
state VARCHAR(3),
postcode VARCHAR(4))
round_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (round_id) REFERENCES round (id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE current_order (
paper_id VARCHAR(20),
subscriber_id VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (paper_id, subscriber_id),
FOREIGN KEY (paper_id) REFERENCES paper (id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
FOREIGN KEY(subscriber_id) REFERENCES subscriber (id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE receipt (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
receipt_date DATE,
paid_till_date DATE,
paper_id VARCHAR(20),
subscriber_id VARCHAR(10))
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Now table paper has a primary key ID, it is referenced by paper_id in table current_order.
Table subscriber has a primary key ID, it is referenced by subscriber_id in table current_order.
Tabe current_order has a composite primary key (paper_id,subscriber_id).
So these three table has been linked together through the foreign key relationship.

If I want to have the last table receipt linked with these three table, how do I do that? My idea was to 
1:set a compound foreign key (paper_id,subscriber_id) referencing to the compound primary key (paper_id,subscriber_id) in table current_order.
2:set two single foreign key (paper_id) and (subscriber_id) referencing to (paper_id) and )subscriber_id) in table current_order separately.

Neither method worked and it came up with error 1452:cannot add or update child row.
So I am really desperate to know what is the proper way to set relationship between table receipt and table current_order?
here is the E-R Digram:

[E-R DIGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edeED.png)

There is two links between table receipt and table current_order and I am required to set relationship according to that.

Comment: You can have multiple, separate `foreign_key` fields on a table. Just add the `foreign_key` relationships to the `paper_id` and `subscriber_id` to the `receipt` table? Also,  imo, unless _every_ `receipt` has `paper_id` and `subscriber_id`, I question whether they should be on the 'receipt' table, at all?

Comment: yes every receipt does have a paper-id and a subscriber_id

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a mysql expert but i would try this:

```
CREATE TABLE receipt (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
receipt_date DATE,
paid_till_date DATE,
paper_id VARCHAR(20),
subscriber_id VARCHAR(10),
FOREIGN KEY (paper_id,subscriber_id) REFERENCES current_order (paper_id,subscriber_id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

does it works?

Comment: yes the code itself is right, however it did not work before because some values of these two columns in table receipt and  were different from those in table current_order. THANKS

Comment: you're welcome. please tag my post as answer or upvote it if helped to solve your issue.